# How do I get localized names of application in python?

Tags: python, localization

This code gives me only English application name if .desktop file does not have "Name[*]" options (like in totem.desktop) but only "X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain: totem":

```
from gi.repository import Gio
app = Gio.app_info_get_default_for_type('video/x-flv', True)
print app.get_name()
```

This like code gives me proper result for vlc.desktop.

Ubuntu Dash shows proper localized names for all applications.

How do I get localized names of application in python?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This code works perfect:

```
from gi.repository import Gio
from xdg.DesktopEntry import DesktopEntry

app = Gio.app_info_get_default_for_type('video/x-flv', True)
filename = app.get_filename()
de = DesktopEntry(filename)

print de.getName()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the value for `X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain`, and get the translation from that domain with something like `gettext.dgettext(domain, app_name)`. Most app names aren't/shouldn't be translated, though.

Comment: Thanks! Should I get domain directly from .desktop files?

Comment: Yes, it appears you'll have to load the .desktop file with the GKeyFile API directly to get the domain. I don't see any any API methods to do so in the app info APIs.