# Where are localized interface names of launcher items defined if they are not in the .desktop file?

Tags: unity, application-development, launcher, unity-dash

#### Naming of a launcher

***- In most cases...***
The *interface* -name of a launcher, in most cases, is defined in the (first) line, starting with:

```
Name=
```

of its corresponding `.desktop` file:

[image]

***- Localized naming from the .desktop file***
For *localized* naming, some applications (like Thunderbird) use extensive lists with launguage- specific names:

[image]

***- But where is the localized name defined if it's not defined in the .desktop file?***
In some cases however, the icon is named differently, but the name is nowhere in the `.desktop`file:

[image]

Where is this name connected with the `.desktop` file?

#### Context

A few years ago, I wrote the [QLE Quicklist editor](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/qle-unity-quicklist-editor-20-released.html). That version used the International interface names. I am rewriting it now in `Gtk+`, but need to find a reliable way to display the localized launcher names.

#### Note

No doubt, this question is related to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226304/how-do-i-get-localized-names-of-application-in-python), but not exactly a dupe; I'd like to know where the information is stored to fetch the localized name(s) myself.

---

#### EDIT

As a proof, the content of `gnome-screenshot.desktop`, named *Scermafdruk* localized  (translated: *Screenshot*). No trace of the string "Scermafdruk" in the file...

[AU]

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Screenshot
Comment=Save images of your screen or individual windows
Keywords=snapshot;capture;print;
Exec=gnome-screenshot --interactive
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=applets-screenshooter
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Utility;
NotShowIn=KDE;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-utils
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=screenshot
Actions=Screen;Window;Area
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-screenshot

[Desktop Action Screen]
Name=Take a Screenshot of the Whole Screen
Exec=gnome-screenshot
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Take a Screenshot of the Current Window
Exec=gnome-screenshot -w
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Area]
Name=Take a Screenshot of a Selected Area
Exec=gnome-screenshot -a
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Comment: They have to be. Have you checked *both* locations for **.desktop** files? One is the obvious `/usr/share/applications` and the other is your personal folder in `~/.local/share/applications/`. If a file is present in both, then your user-specific entry is used I believe.

Comment: That's rather puzzling, I'm also only aware of these two locations for the .desktop files. Maybe someone else knows more.  Did you check if maybe the name of the .desktop file has been localized as well? (Would not be the smartest thing to do and I doubt it)

Comment: Have you tried recursively grep everything in /usr ?

Comment: @Serg good one! How could I forget, running now, I will do the same in my home dir. Have to teach now, I will look for the outcome when I am ready :)

Comment: "Binary file `/usr/share/locale-langpack/nl/LC_MESSAGES/gnome-screenshot.mo` matches".

Comment: Hi Jos, there seems to be a lot of truth in your comment. In `python` the output of `test = gettext.find("gnome-screenshot"); print(test)`:  `/usr/share/locale-langpack/nl/LC_MESSAGES/gnome-screenshot.mo` ...Looking further to get to understand what is happening exactly here.

Comment: You know about [.po and .mo files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext), don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out yourself while testing, the entry responsible for such behavior is:

```
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-screenshot
```

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Internationalisation/Packaging:

> DESKTOP ENTRIES
>
> Translations of [desktop entries](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec) (.desktop files) are also stripped out and included in language packs.
>
> Contrary to what other distros do (except currently OpenSUSE), the translations are not expected to be in the .desktop files themselves (static translations), but rather in the same .mo file of the application, from which they are then loaded at runtime. We do this in order to be able to translate them in Launchpad and to ship them in language packs, so that they can be edited and updated by Ubuntu translators.
>
> The runtime loading is done by patches to [patch glib](https://launchpad.net/glib/+bug/3935) and [kdelibs](http://patches.ubuntu.com/k/kde4libs/extracted/kubuntu_56_langpacks_desktop_files.diff), which recognises the the **X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain** [additional key](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s08.html) we add to all Ubuntu .desktop files and adds gettext support when loading them. Note that if the .desktop file already contains translations, these static translations will be preferred.
>
> Adding the X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain= key is done during build time in the packaging either automatically with the package build system or (increasingly rarely) with patches.

In other words, that means that the patched version of `glib` and `kdelib` on Ubuntu use the `X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain` key to add gettext support at runtime if a translation is not available by other means in the desktop file, translation which is retrieved from the application's .mo file.

Notice also that this implies that the support for the `X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain` key is a Ubuntu-specific implementation, and that desktop files using the `X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain` are only portable across distributions that use the same patched version of `glib` / `kdelib`.

Comment: Excellent and complete answer. One question on *"we add to all Ubuntu .desktop files and adds gettext support when loading them"* I guess you don't mean *all* Ubuntu applications include the string in their  `.desktop`file? (Thunderbird doesn't for example, and there are quite a few more)

Comment: @JacobVlijm That I don't know, I didn't write the page on the Wiki :) However it seems like most of them do have the entry, while only a few do not (run `grep -r '^X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain' /usr/share/applications` to see which desktop files which have it and `grep -lR '^X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain' /usr/share/applications` to see which desktop files don't have it). I'd guess that either the Wiki is imprecise or we're reading that wrongly or they just forgot to add it.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Typo, I meant `grep -LR '^X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain' /usr/share/applications` to see which desktop files don't have it.

Comment: I have 139 `.desktop` files in`/usr/share/applications` without the string. I think the link is a bit optimistic on the implementation :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Perhaps I found the reason, see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Internationalisation/Packaging), very fist paragraph: "Packages in main and restricted don't contain translations (\*.mo) files themselves, they are stripped during the build on the Launchpad buildds and put into language-pack-\* packages instead. This is done in an attempt to bundle the translations you're interested in and cut down the occupied space.": I suppose packages outside of `main` and `restricted` are not bound to include the key?

Comment: Also I very recently reinstalled my system (i.e. I have a very few packages not included by default), and this is what I get: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15931605/

Comment: This is mine (the figures are a bit different from my first (python) count: http://pastebin.com/pDM8WRcT The figures should probably be corrected by checking on "NoDisplay=true", but it makes clear it is not by definition.

Comment: @JacobVlijm We're also forgetting that a package might not have any translation at all. That and my second to last comment *could* explain why you have such a high number of desktop files missing the key. Perhaps someone more involved in Ubuntu development could give a better explanation (maybe we could ask jokerdino / Jos).

Comment: :) I continued in chat :)